# C dynamic struct assignment with pointer declaration

Tags: c, struct, typedef

The program crashes near assignment. How could I get it to work ? Thanks in advance. Sorry if it is repost. Could not find similar example anywhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _kv
{
    char *key;
    char *value;
} _kv;

typedef struct _kvs
{
    _kv *kv;
    int size;
} _kvs;

main()
{
    _kvs a;

    a.kv[0].key     = "This is key One";
    a.kv[0].value   = "This is value One";

    a.size = 1;

    printf("%s = %s\n", a.kv[0].key, a.kv[0].value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created pointers but did not make room for the memory.  You need to associate some memory with the pointers by possibly using `malloc`.

```
a.size = 1;
a.kv = malloc ( a.size * sizeof ( _kv ) );
int i;
const int string_sz = 80;   // Or whatever else the string size should be
for ( i = 0; i < a.size; i++ )
{
    a.kv[i].key = malloc ( string_sz );
    a.kv[i].value = malloc ( string_sz );
}

strcpy ( a.kv[i].key, "This is key one" );
strcpy ( a.kv[i].value, "This is value one" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized pointers cannot be deferenced, you must first make sure they point at valid memory.

```
_kvs a;

a.kv = malloc(1 * sizeof *a.kv);  /* Allocate a single _kv. */
a.kv[0].key = "key";
a.kv[0].value = "value";
a.size = 1;
```

Or you could use memory on the stack:

```
_kv my_kvs[1];
_kvs a;

a.kv = my_kvs;
a.kv[0].key = "key";
a.kv[0].value = "value";
a.size = 1;
```